# How do return to previous tasks in BPMN 2.0?

Tags: bpmn

I am creating a business process model with Visio 2010 and was wondering how to go back a few tasks (loop)?

**Example**: a document can be approved or rejected. When the document is approved, the process ends and that's it. When a document is rejected, the process should start over from "Task 2".

How do I visually show this the best way? Creating a task with "Start At Task 2.1" seems wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is straightforward. You just draw a sequence flow from document rejection to `Task 2`. See the diagram below.

[image: BPMN diagram]